# how to check the first three characters in a variable?

Tags: php

I have a viariable that contains something like this `ab_123456789`

how can i check if the variable starts with `ab_`?

thanks,
sebastian

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Another way using [`substr`](http://php.net/substr):

```
if (substr('ab_123456789', 0, 3) === 'ab_')
```

Here `substr` is used to take the first 3 bytes starting at position 0 as a string that is then compared to `'ab_'`. If you want to add case-insensivity, use [`strcasecmp`](http://php.net/strcasecmp).

---

**Edit**    To make the use more comfortable, you could use the following `startsWith` function:

```
function startsWith($str, $prefix, $case_sensitivity=false) {
    if ($case_sensitivity) {
        return substr($str, 0, strlen($prefix)) === $prefix;
    } else {
        return strcasecmp(substr($str, 0, strlen($prefix)), $prefix) === 0;
    }
}
```

Note that these functions do not support multi-byte characters as only bytes are compared. An equivalent function with multi-byte support could look like this:

```
function mb_startsWith($str, $prefix, $case_sensitivity=false) {
    if ($case_sensitivity) {
        return mb_substr($str, 0, mb_strlen($prefix)) === $prefix;
    } else {
        return mb_strtolower(mb_substr($str, 0, mb_strlen($prefix))) === mb_strtolower($prefix);
    }
}
```

Here the character encoding of both strings is assumed to be the [internal character encoding](http://php.net/mb_internal_encoding).

Answer (score 7):

Use regular expressions

```
$var = "ab_123456789";
if(preg_match('/^ab_/', $var, $matches)){
    /*your code here*/
}
```

Comment: preg_match will return 0 if nothing matches or an integer representing the number of times the match was found.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
$text = "ab_123456789";
if(strpos($text, "ab_") === 0)
{
    // Passed the test
}
```

Comment: Note that `strpos` will search until a match is found or the end of the string is reached.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy, as your string can be accessed like an array of characters. So you just have to do something like :

```
if ($var[0] == "a" && $var[1] == "b" && $var[2] == "c")
  return true
```

You also could use a find function from php library.

Comment: Strings aren't arrays in PHP.

Comment: @Daniel Egeberg: But strings can be accessed like arrays. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr

Comment: It's not an Array object, but you can access it as you do for an array.

Comment: @Gumbo: I think Daniel Egeberg means that the answer implies that a string is an array, which it isn't. The part about accessing using array notation is correct though.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to get a sub string. e.g.  `substr('ab_123456789', 0, 3);`